# Why does this drop-down div disappear when I move over the iframe below it?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, sass, haml

I have a header that contains a dropdown menu. Beneath that header is the "body" of content, which is filled completely by an iframe. When you hover over the "Pick a game..." dropdown menu, and you move your mouse over the part of that div that is over the iframe, that div disappears as if you moved your mouse off of it. See the pen below if you want to try it yourself.

Also, if you turn on the iframe's border, then the border will show through the dropdown. This leads me to believe that somehow the iframe is rendering above the dropdown div; however, even with the iframe z-indexed back, it still shows.
Any ideas as to why I can't get to my second dropdown option?

Pen: https://codepen.io/Spirit_Ryu/pen/PJwrKp/

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Baumans;
  src: url("./data/Baumans-Regular.ttf");
}
body {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #666666;
}

iframe {
  border: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#visibledata {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Baumans, sans-serif;
}

#header {
  width: 100vw;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}
#header #name {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20pt;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#header #pickagame {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background: #e8e8e8;
}
#header #pickagame .dropdown {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
#header #pickagame .dropdown li {
  padding-top: 8px;
}
#header #pickagame:hover .dropdown {
  display: inline;
}

#page {
  position: absolute;
  top: 63px;
  height: 100vh;
}
#page #game {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='./data/index.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='visibledata'>
      <div id='header'>
        <a href='./index.html'>
          <div id='name'>All-Star Favorites Arcade</div>
        </a>
        <div id='pickagame'>
          Pick a game...
          <div style='float: right'>▼</div>
          <div class='dropdown'>
            <a href='./data/ArmorMayhem.html' target='gameWindow'>
              <li>Armor Mayhem</li>
            </a>
            <a href='./data/ArmorMayhem.html' target='gameWindow'>
              <li>Armor Mayhem</li>
            </a>
            <a href='./data/ArmorMayhem.html' target='gameWindow'>
              <li>Armor Mayhem</li>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id='page'>
        <iframe id='game' name='gameWindow'></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to have your list elements inside a `<ul>`, that's the first issue

Comment: @PaigeMeinke OCD... lol, will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the element with an id of 'page' is position: absolute, and the dropdown is not. Even when the dropdown is at a higher index than the element with an id of 'page' that the iframe lives in, it will not matter since absolute positioned elements will sit on top of any elements that are position: static underneath it.

Comment: Thanks! If I add `position: absolute` to the `#pickagame` div, it won't fix it. Instead, by removing the latter from the `#page` div, that fixes it.

Comment: Sweet, glad I'm glad I could help you continue with your coding. The more code in this world, the better ! : )